# How to remove logic from rails view when every case have diferent styleing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, logic, presenter

My problem is that i have logic in my view but every case have different styleing. It`s not problem to move logic to .ex presenter but how to deal with styleing

```
- trumps.each do |trump| 
%tr
 %td
  - if trump.isgreate
    .some_style
     .some_style--button
      =link_to trump.picture
  - else
    .someother_style
     .someother_style--button
      =link_to trump.lies
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to move logic into View Helpers.

```rb
# create helper in relevant *helper.rb

def outer_div(trump)
  trump.isgreate ? 'some_style' : 'someother_style'
end

def inner_button_div(trump)
  trump.isgreate ? 'some_style--button' : 'someother_style--button'
end

dev link_to_trump
  link_to(trump.isgreate ? trump.picture : trump.lies)
end
```

```
- trumps.each do |trump| 
  %tr
   %td
     %div{class: outer_div(trump)}
       %div{class: inner_button_div(trump) }
         = link_to_trump(trump)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about css classes?

Styling is not supposed to be done in controllers or models anyway.

Although for any answer to be relevant you have to provide your development environment.  Such as the ruby and rails version you're using, and even your operating system...things can be really different depending on this.

Normally people aren't going to try to help you, but I was once like this and asked questions without first looking things up.

For Rails 6, 
add a css file to app/assets/stylesheets.  You should see something like this in your application.html.erb file (global view file)

```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', :'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>
```

Use your controllers to handle user input and set variables/pull model data for your views.

Good luck buddy.